# Trouble Switching Classes on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, android-emulator

I'm a beginner programmer so please bear with me. This app runs fine but when I try to open up a new class, the app force closes. Can someone please help me with this problem?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_HELP:
          Intent localIntent = new Intent();
          localIntent.setClass(MyClass.this, Help.class);
          startActivity(localIntent);
          break; }
```

The Manifest Looks like:

```
<activity
        android:name=".HELP"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
```

I have tried multiple times with different ways to start an intent including

```
startActivity(new Intent(com.myapp.HELP));
```

and then setting up an intent filter but this proved fruitless as well.

Some additional information. In logcat, I get this error:

```
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.myapp/com.mayapp.Help}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I have found other users who have found this problem, and they said it was a problem with eclipse, no the code. Is there anyone that can help with the eclipse problem?

Comment: you have register Help.class in manifast?

Comment: the help class registered in wrong way in ur manifest  you need to put like <activity
        android:name=".Help"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" > in ur manifest
    </activity>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_HELP:
        startActivity(new Intent(MyClass.this,Help.class));
          break; }
```

in Manifest:

```
   <application
            android:icon="@drawable/mj_icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MyClass"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".Help"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
    </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Java class names are case sensitive. Your manifest uses HELP and your Java code uses Help. Change the manifest to .Help to fix.

Answer (score 0):

rigister  Help.class in Manifest  as:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Help"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
```